# Different placement of curly braces

Tags: c

Sometimes when I look up videos at Youtube for better explanation and usually these people places the curly braces differently.

Note that , I'm new to the coding world.

1st placement.

```
for(int i=1 ; i < 6 ; i++)
{

    //Statements

}
```

2nd placement

```
for(int i=1 ; i < 6 ; i++){

    //Statements

}
```

These 2 codes actually functions the same , it just has different placement of the curly braces.

What's the difference of these 2 placements? Why do some others use the 2nd placement instead of the first one? I actually prefer the first one, because its easier to spot errors and looks neat.

Comment: That's code style. Functionally the snippets are the same. It's opinion-based.

Comment: It does not matter. Some programmers just like one or other style. In most cases the compiles ignores the whitespace - and you can write the whole program in the one line

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style

Comment: The only rule on styles is: No matter which style you use, be consistent. Just use one. And this does not just apply to how to indent. This `int i=1 ; i < 6 ; i++`, for example, already is inconsistent.

Comment: @alk could you explain how is " int i=1 ; i < 6 ; i++ " inconsistent? I am just curious what do you mean by that.

Comment: Either use spaces around operators or don't: `i=1 ... i<6` **or** `i = 1 ... i < 6`

Comment: @alk , Thanks for clarifying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st and 2nd are the same.
The only difference is the coding style. 
While you work for a company X they tend to use one coding style just for the sake of consistency. It does not matter if you use the first or second style as long as you are writing it, in the same way, all the time.
It just might confuse other developers who will have to read your code at some point.